# PCIEx16_2 Causes Black Screen

Tags: ubuntu, drivers, graphics-card, motherboard, pci-express

I'm trying to use two RX480s with an ASUS B350-Plus motherboard running Ubuntu 16.04. Everything works fine when I only have one 480 plugged in to the `PCEx16_1` slot, but if I plug anything into the `PCEx16_2` slot, I get stuck at a black screen on boot. I've tried both cards in the first slot and they work fine so I know the issue is not with the the cards; it's specifically the second slot.

**Config:**

- CPU: Ryzen 3 1200
- GPU: 2x RX480s
- MB: ASUS B350-plus
- OS: Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS (Kernel 4.13.0-32-generic)
- Graphic Driver: AMDGPU-PRO Driver Version 17.50 for Ubuntu 16.04.3

**Steps to Reproduce:**

Plugging either GPU into `PCIEx16_2`

**Expected Behavior:**

Boot into Ubuntu normally, be able to use both cards.

**Actual Behavior:**
BIOS screen displays and then screen goes black and stays that way.

Update:
Doing some digging revealed that PCIEx_16 shares lanes with SATA1. I moved the hard drive from SATA1 to SATA4 and successfully managed to get to the grub boot loader. However trying to enter the os I got the following results. 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/l5sfX.jpg

I rebooted a second time and got this after passing the bootloader 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/WmiPg.jpg

Comment: PSU?  Provide specifics

Comment: 750W bronze Corsair, so it should have enough power for both cards

Comment: Is the motherboard running the latest UEFI version?

Comment: I just updated it but still no luck. Made some slight progress though. See post

Comment: You have a segment fault in your kernel.  I would recommend updating your kernel, whatever bug you have may already be fixed in a new kernel.

Comment: I managed to log in with `text acpi=off` and ran `sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade`. However, if I don't include the `acpi=off` i get the same hanging error. any idea why that is or what that impacts?